# Data type conversion from SQL Server to SAP BW

Tags: sql, sql-server, sap-bw

We want to use a "db connect" data source to load data into BW. We have a CHAR field that is not being recognize by the "db extractor" as CUKY data type in SAP.

We've changed the data type to multiple different formats and types but there is no equivalent in SQL Server for CUKY data type to use as a currency key in BW.

Ideally, we would like the field `CUR` to be `CUKY(5)` but it is showing as `CHAR(10)` in BW even though the view is `CHAR(5)` in SQL Server.

How do we tell SAP BW to set that field as CUKY?

Comment: How did you define the datasource? Show us the full flow with screenshots